# Union Type missing properties

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

Say I have the following types:

```
type MessageType = 'example1' | 'example2' | 'example3'

type MessageHead = {
  +type: MessageType
}

type BaseBody = {
  +payload?: any,
  +data?: any
}

type LabelledBody = {
  +labelName: string
}

type MessageBody = BaseBody | LabelledBody

type Message = MessageHead & MessageBody
```

And I then consume a message like so:

```
[{name: 'example1'}, {name: 'potato'}].find(thing => thing.name === message.labelName)
```

Resulting in the following flow exception:

```
Cannot get message.labelName because:
 • all branches are incompatible:
    • Either property labelName is missing in MessageHead [1].
    • Or property labelName is missing in BaseBody [2].
 • ... 1 more error.
```

With `type Message = MessageHead & MessageBody` being displayed as the violated type

What I don't understand is why my Union Type doesn't allow for a message with a labelname?

Edit: Tryflow link:[Tryflow link](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzCAVc0C8UDkEAHkgLZgA2EAjHlAD75GkUQBMtDBxZlAzHgCgBoSLATI0ACQhIAJlFwBvAVCgBqERABcYxKgxYBAXyGaoAISTwI5gPayQCqMtVqwSEOVtyA-DqQAdiAANCrqskjASH5QgSDGplhQADJIAEYQ5JSydg5OLurk6ZkAcqTaUPDAAE4AlgEoCcJJcHpouY64ltYd9CnFWRA59vHNoq0SOLqT0nJQAGTT+h1CAMa2AVVQRABiAK4Bq04AFCTi+joT+gCUCgB8zmEA2ooB5TpczJQ0RsHOb2cPmBbFFgLY8EYALoAOgAZvVZMdgAALeooe5QFFo6EAnDYXBnNoQaFFDLkMpna7GIA)

Comment: we wrestled with a similar problem a couple weeks back and eventually gave up, switching to a simpler pattern where we didn't attempt to 'extend' types, and just used a single type with optionals where necessary. Not as nice, but worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your union type *does* allow for a `Message` with a labelname. The problem is that it also allows for a `Message` *without* a label name. Consider the union you've got on this line:

```
type MessageBody = BaseBody | LabelledBody
```

This means that `MessageBody` can be either look like this:

```
type BaseBody = {
  +payload?: any,
  +data?: any
}
```

or

```
type LabelledBody = {
  +labelName: string
}
```

Taking this a step further, we can perform the intersection between MessageBody and MessageHead and see that the shape of Message can one of these two cases:

(case 1)

```
{
  +type: MessageType,  // From MessageHead
  +payload?: any,      // From BaseBody
  +data?: any          // From BaseBody
}
```

(case 2)

```
{
  +type: MessageType,  // From MessageHead
  +labelName: string   // From LabelledBody
}
```

So when Flow sees you're accessing the labelName of the `message` object, it believes (correctly), that the `message` object might look like case 1 (above). If we're in case 1, then you can't access the labelName, since it doesn't exist, so it throws an error. The simplest way to get around this is to create two types of messages, one with a `labelName` and one with the `payload` and `data` properties. Then you can annotate your function as receiving one of the types:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzCAVc0C8UDkEAHkgLZgA2EAjHlAD75GkUQBMtDBxZlAzHgCgBoSLATI0ACQhIAJlFwBvAVCgBqERABcYxKgxYBAXyGaoAISTwI5gPayQCqMtVqwSEOVtyA-DqQAdiAANCrqskjASH5QgSDGplhQADJIAEYQ5JSydg5OLurk6ZkAcqTaUPDAAE4AlgEoCcJJcHpouY64ltYd9CnFWRA59vHNoq0SOLqT0nJQAGTT+h2J4+L6AOq1wAAWqRnkThP6s-KL+5nZKwIAxrYBVVBEAGIArgE3TgAUJOtoOsc0FtdhdyABKBQAPmcYQA2ooAuUdFxmJQaEZgs5Eb9kWBbFFgLY8EYALoAOgAZvVZF9dvUUFCoHSGmTsThsLhfm0IGSigcyr8wcYgA))

```
type MessageWithLabel = MessageHead & LabelledBody

const exFunc = (message: MessageWithLabel) => {
  [{name: 'example1'}, {name: 'potato'}].find(thing => thing.name === message.labelName)
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a [disjoint union](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions) to tell flow which case you're using. This strategy involves setting a property (e.g. `type`) which tells flow which type of object we're dealing with.

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#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))

```
type MessageWithBody = {|
  +type: 'base',
  +payload?: any,
  +data?: any
|}

type MessageWithLabel = {|
  +type: 'labelled',
  +labelName: string
|}

type Message = MessageWithBody | MessageWithLabel

const exFunc = (message: Message) => {
  if (message.type === 'labelled') {
    const labelName = message.labelName
    return [{name: 'example1'}, {name: 'potato'}].find(thing => thing.name === labelName)

    // Sidenote: 
    // I had to extract labelName to a constant for Flow to typecheck this correctly.
    // So if we used thing.name === message.labelName Flow will throw an Error.
    // If you don't extract it right away, flow thinks the Message may have changed
    // after pretty much any non-trivial action. Obviously it doesn't change in this
    // example, but, hey, Flow isn't perfect.
    // Reference: https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/#toc-refinement-invalidations
  } else {
     // Do something for the 'base' type of message
  }
}
```